Blazor "Individual Accounts" without email address
The standard Blazor app template with "Individual Accounts" enabled for auth creates these files.

This assumes users will have email as a primary sign-in, and then have 0..1 additional External logins.
I want my user to not have to specify an email address - their primary ID could be twitter/facebook/google etc, and then add additional identifiers - including email if they wish.
Has anyone done this?
